# How to convert time formatter in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

Currently i am working in iPhone application, Here i have using `NSString` to store `(2012-07-11 11:49:55 +0000)` and using `NSDateFormatter` to convert the date and time but the output comes `05:19:55`, but i want `11:49:55`, please any one help me

Here i tried the source code for your reference

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringwithformat:%@,(2012-07-11 11:49:55 +0000)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss";
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString]);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system time zone is not +0000. So the time is formatted according to it. The solution is to set same time zone to GMT (+0000).

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are changing the `TimeZone`, please comment out the following line and it should give back the time you provided in the `dateString`:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

Comment: Sorry, got confused by the way you handle the `dateString`. I usually specify the `dateFormatter` to resemble more closely the input string. Is there a special reason you don't specify it like this  `dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";` ?